# Why can't I color my bar chart when I make it show percentages?

Tags: r, ggplot2

With the code written below I do get the output to look exactly how I want it to, but if I were to add on the y=..prop.. and group = 1 argument it wont't run if fill = TicketClass is left. But if I remove that it just results in a grey bar chart. Is there any way to fix this?

This is how I wrote it first and it ran fine:

```
Titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = TicketClass,
             fill = TicketClass)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 3, 
                                         name = "Moonrise3")) +
  labs(x = "Ticket Class",
      y = "Number of Passengers",
      title = "Passengers Aboard the Titanic.",
      caption = "Data from the Titanic R Package.") +
  theme_bw()
```

To show percentages/proportions I've written it like this, and it won't run:

```
 Titanic %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = TicketClass,
              y = ..prop.., 
              group = 1,
              fill = TicketClass)) +
   geom_bar() +
   scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 3, 
                                          name = "Moonrise3")) +
   labs(x = "Ticket Class",
        y = "Number of Passengers",
        title = "Passengers Aboard the Titanic.",
        caption = "Data from the Titanic R Package.") +
   theme_bw()
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note I have used titanic dataset from here: https://rpubs.com/kelvinsonmwangi/645367 using `Pclass`

replace the `fill` aesthetics by `fill(..x..)`:

```
library(ggplot)
library(wesanderson)

titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pclass,
             y = ..prop.., 
             group = 1,
             fill = factor(..x..))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(n = 3, 
                                         name = "Moonrise3")) +
  labs(x = "Ticket Class",
       y = "Number of Passengers",
       title = "Passengers Aboard the Titanic.",
       caption = "Data from the Titanic R Package.") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]